# Changing Checkpoint Trusted Client list from AnyHost

Tags: checkpoint

I have been tasked with locking down our Checkpoint smart console R81 access as currently the Trusted Client list is set to any host and nothing else.

[image]

I have experience of adding and removing hosts from Trusted Client lists when there is no AnyHost 'rule' but with this I am nervous about adding specific devices and then deleting the AnyHost. My hesitancy is that I could lock everyone out of the firewall if I get it wrong or overlook something. How will I know that my added devices are working correctly before deleting AnyHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In extreme, you can use the console port to regain access to the appliance - I'd familiarize myself with the console interface first.

Regulating access is a good thing (a must many might say). You should also consider configuring a dedicated VLAN for management.